# GroupRectangles Opencv not working

Tags: python, opencv, crash, tracking

Hi i trying simple cascade people detection and i want to use cv2.groupRectangles(), but whenever i use it it crashes:

**OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype)) in unknown function, file ......\src\opencv\modules\core\src\copy.cpp, line 212

**This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.******

my code:

```
    rects = cascade.detectMultiScale(img, scaleFactor=1.05, minNeighbors=3, minSize=(minSize, minSize), maxSize=( maxSize,  maxSize), flags=cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING)
    #print rects
    rectList, weights = cv2.groupRectangles(rects, 1, 0.2)
    if len(rects) == 0:
            return []
    rects[:,2:] += rects[:,:2]
    return rects
```

Everything worked fine till groupRectangles use.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to convert *rects* from  *numpy.array* to *list*.

```
    rectList, weights = cv2.groupRectangles(np.array(rects).tolist(), 1, 0.2)
```

That worked for me.

Comment: This works but I was already passing a properly formed list to groupRectangles and it was failing. When I print the list out and copy/paste it directly into the function it also works.. So I imagine there is some simpler solution...

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to **make sure all the values in each rect are integers**.

For visual reference, the list should be formatted as:

```
[[int, int, int, int], [int ,int ,int ,int], ...]
```

As far as I can tell every type of integer should work but numpy in my case likes to convert to int32 which works fine, but int16 might be best to save space - you decide what you need...

int16   Integer (-32768 to 32767)

int32   Integer (-2147483648 to 2147483647)

int64   Integer (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807)

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html